# Align division bottom left

Tags: css, user-interface

image reference below link

[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjXWW.png)

https://paste.pics/G9OS7

html

```
<div class="basicinfo">
      <div class="dandt">1:00 AM Tuesday 13 April 2022</div>
      <div class="location">Toronto</div>
      <div class="weathertype">Cloudy</div>
      <div class="temp">8 Degree C</div>
</div>
```

but unable to align them according to the image

css

```
.basicinfo {
  position: relative;
}

.dandt {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  color: white;
}

.location {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  color: white;
}
```

Learning HTML CSS
pardon my mistakes
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which image? There is no image in your template

Comment: updated now. can u check again please @gguney

Comment: So you have another div outside this div? And it has image background?

Comment: There's a typo in your CSS, "badicinfo" instead of "basicinfo"

Comment: actually the image is gonna cover whole page
but this basic info section will position in the bottom side of this page
there will some other section 

https://paste.pics/G9OS7

Comment: thanks @Ownagin 
but that didn't solved the prblm

Comment: You may wanna move the dandt and location divs to the parent div, where the background image is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to debug without the reproducible code but if I understood it correctly you want to position that at the bottom left. You can create a div that is absolute with everything inside of it.

Assuming `container` is your parent div (the card)

```css
.container {
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.basicinfo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
}

.weather-display {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="basicinfo">
    <div class="dandt">1:00 AM Tuesday 13 April 2022</div>
    <div class="location">Toronto</div>
    <div class="weather-display">
      <div>☁️</div>
      <div>
        <div class="weathertype">Cloudy</div>
        <div class="temp">8 Degree C</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```